# 'PlayerStatsForm' object has no attribute 'username'

Tags: python, html, django

I am creating a search bar that takes a username and locates that Player in the database. I create a PlayerStatsForm() that takes in the request, searches the database for players with the username from the request, and returns that players stats. I know that the username is being passed by the html form to my python code correctly and the form is passing true for PlayerStatsForm.is_valid() but when I try and call playerstatsform.username it says that the attribute is not found. If I add model = Player and change forms.Form to ModelForm in PlayerStatsForm it tries to insert a player with no username or id into the database and says that the column user_id cannot be null

```
<tr><th><label for="id_username">Username:</label></th><td><input type="text" name="username" value="testuser" required id="id_username"></td></tr>
Internal Server Error: /elousers/elosearch/
```

This is the error from the terminal so is the issue that id=id_username and not name=id_username?

playerstatsform:

```
class PlayerStatsForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        fields = (
            'username',
        )
```

views.py:

```
def elosearch(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("Post was found")
        if 'get_player' in request.POST:
            playerstatsform = PlayerStatsForm(request.POST)
            print("post found")
            if playerstatsform.is_valid():
                player = Player.objects.get(name=playerstatsform.cleaned_data['username'])
                print("player found successfully")
                player_elo = player.elo
                player_name = player.name
                print(player_elo)
                context1 = {'playername': player_name, 'playerelo': player_elo}
                return render('elousers/elosearch.html', context1)
            else:
                invalid_player_entry = "Username not added. Please register below."
                context1 = {'invalid_player': invalid_player_entry}
                return render(request, 'elousers/elosearch.html', context1)
        elif 'addgame' in request.POST:
            gameform = GameForm(data=request.POST)
            if gameform.is_valid():
                gameform.save()
                game_success = "Game Successfully Added!"
                context2 = {'game_display': game_success}
                return render(request, 'elousers/elosearch.html', context2)
            else:
                game_invalid = "Invalid entry. Please try again."
                context2 = {'game_display': game_invalid}
                return render(request, 'elousers/elosearch.html', context2)
        else:
            return render(request, 'elousers/elosearch.html')
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        print("get was called")
        return render(request, 'elousers/elosearch.html')
```

expect the database to query using the username provided by the form but I am getting 'PlayerStatsForm' object has no attribute 'username'

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the value from the `playerstatsform` through the [**`.cleaned_data`** attribute [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.cleaned_data), which is a dictionary. By using `playerstatsform.username`, you get access to the form field, but this will render the HTML representation of the field if you pass it through `str`.

```
def elosearch(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("Post was found")
        if 'get_player' in request.POST:
            playerstatsform = PlayerStatsForm(request.POST)
            if playerstatsform.is_valid():
                player = Player.objects.get(name=playerstatsform.cleaned_data['username'])
                player_elo = player.elo
                player_name = player.name
                context1 = {'playername': player_name, 'playerelo': player_elo}
                return render(request, 'elousers/elosearch.html', context1)
```

Note that it is possible that no `Player` object exists for the given `name`, or perhaps, if that field is not `unique=True`, multiple `Player`s can have that name, so you probably should at least `try`-`catch` these cases, and handle these accordingly.

You thus probably will need to do something like:

```
def elosearch(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("Post was found")
        if 'get_player' in request.POST:
            playerstatsform = PlayerStatsForm(request.POST)
            if playerstatsform.is_valid():
                try:
                    player = Player.objects.get(
                        name=playerstatsform.cleaned_data['username']
                    )
                except (Player.DoesNotExist, Player.MultipleObjectsReturned):
                    player = None
                    player_elo = None
                    player_name = None
                else:
                    player_elo = player.elo
                    player_name = player.name
                context1 = {'playername': player_name, 'playerelo': player_elo}
                return render(request, 'elousers/elosearch.html', context1)
```

Comment: Now that it works the render at the end is returning The view "elousers.views.elosearch didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead." Do you know how to handle the redirect/render such that I can pass this information to the next page correctly?

Comment: @crackerhands: you forgot to write `return` in `return render`. Furthermore you will need to return something for (a) a GET request (probably) and (b) a POST request where the form is *not* valid. This can be a `redirect(..)`, a `render(..)` or something else, but well, something.

Comment: Hi thank you for pointing out the return statement! Now that the post is working it is not proceeding to the if statement where it checks to see if the method is "POST" as the only print to the console is "Post was found" but not the "player was found" print statement after I successfully locate the player from the data base. is this because of the way I have my render statements that it is looping through and going through the loops with a new post data?

Comment: @crackerhands: are you sure your `request.POST` contains (a) a `get_player` key, and (b) a `username` key?

Comment: Sorry to confused but I added a second form check which is why the view looked incomplete but this is the full view.

Comment: it was the get_player key... thank you for the keen eye I apologize for all the menial questions

Comment: @crackerhands: well each codepath should return a HTTP response, so for the `if request.method == 'POST'`, you should make an `else` that returns something, the same for the `if is_player in ...` and `if playerstatform.is_valid()`.